# open source equivalent of service bus, event grid and event hub

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-eventhub, azure-eventgrid

what are the open source equivalents of azure service bus, event grid and event hub?

Event hub is kafka but i don't know what the equivalents for the other two are.

Comment: for service bus, you can consider using [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/), or find other one from this [page](https://www.g2.com/products/azure-service-bus/competitors/alternatives). But I cannot find a open-source alternative for event grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Like Service Bus, there are [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/), [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/), [ZeroMQ](https://zeromq.org/), etc.
- Like Event Grid, there are [Knative Eventing](https://knative.dev/docs/eventing/), [Argo Events](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-events/), etc. (Cloud Native / K8s)